Exposed Points and Equivalent Topologies
Let $X$ be a locally convex topological vector space under two topologies $\tau_1$, $\tau_2.$ If the two topologies coincide on a compact (w.r.t. both topologies) convex $K\subseteq X,$ must the exposed points w.r.t. each topology also coincide?
Here $x$ is exposed in $(K,\tau_j)$ if there exists a $\tau_j$-continuous functional on $X$ which achieves a unique maximum in $K$ at $x.$
I figure the answer is no, since the collection of functionals can vary between them despite their coincidence on a subset. However, it doesn’t seem unreasonable the very fact they coincide forces their functionals to behave the same on that subset. Consider the sentence from the Operator Topologies Wikipedia page: "In locally convex spaces, closure of convex sets can be characterized by the continuous linear functionals."

No. Let $X = c_0(\mathbb{N})$, $\tau_1$ be the locally convex topology generated by the sup norm, and $\tau_2$ be the locally convex topology generated by the seminorms $\|(\alpha_n)\|_{(\beta_n)} = |\sum_n \alpha_n\beta_n|$ where $(\beta_n) \in c_{00}(\mathbb{N})$, where $c_{00}(\mathbb{N})$ is the space of finitely supported sequences. Let $K = \{(\alpha_n) \in X: 0 \leq \alpha_n \leq \frac{1}{n}, \forall n\}$. It is clear that $K$ is convex. Both $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ restrict to the topology of pointwise convergence on $K$, so the two topologies coincide on $K$ and $K$ is compact w.r.t. them. However, $(1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \cdots) \in K$ is exposed in $(K, \tau_1)$, as, for example, the $\tau_1$-continuous linear functional $c_0(\mathbb{N}) \ni (\alpha_n) \mapsto \sum_n \frac{1}{2^n}\alpha_n$ achieves its unique maximum in $K$ at $(1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \cdots)$, whereas any $\tau_2$-continuous linear functional must be of the form $c_0(\mathbb{N}) \ni (\alpha_n) \mapsto \sum_n \alpha_n\beta_n$ for some $(\beta_n) \in c_{00}(\mathbb{N})$, from which it follows that no exposed points for $(X, \tau_2)$ exist at all, as you can arbitrarily modify $(\alpha_n)$ outside the support of $(\beta_n)$ without changing the value of the linear functional.
